# Mysqli - update or Insert if not exist

Tags: php, mysql, json

Hi Guys i have a table with the following php script

```
$host="host"; // Host name
$username="username"; // Mysql username
$password="password"; // Mysql password
$db_name="dbname"; // Database name
$tbl_name="table"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$url = "http://api.erpk.org/citizen/profile/3121752.json?key=Yn3AsG80";
$json = $json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json, true);

// Get values from form
$id=$_GET['id'];
$citid=$data['id'];
$citname=$data['name'];
$level=$data['level'];
$status=$data['army']['role'];
$citizenship=$data['citizenship']['name'];
$mu=$data['army']['name'];

// update data in mysql database
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET citid='$citid', citname='$citname', level='$level', status='$status', status='$status', citizenship='$citizenship', mu='$mu' WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully updated.
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='list_records.php'>View result</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
```

here is my problem, the update form works, however when its SUCCESSFUL the data is not updating even though it passes

```
// if successfully updated.
```

where have i gone wrong, im not sure

Comment: Can you try outputting `$result`? What does it contain? Btw, you're updating `status` twice. Also, what does the title have to do with the question? You might wanna look into [INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax

Comment: ok i will try the suggestion, and see how i get on

Comment: using my data above i am not sure where to place **ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;** or **UPDATE table SET c=c+1 WHERE a=1;** if i could have an example using my data shown above it would be much appreciated, my duplicate key is citid

Comment: http://d.pr/i/Yzwc they show you how to use it in the docs. For you the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;` should work.

Comment: i tried it, but for some reason i get the error which i posted below, but im not sure if i coded it correctly